# MockMVC in junit tests - checking result for List<Object> and Map<Enum, Object>

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockmvc

I have problems with mockMVC and test written with that. My tests fails.
I have two tests methods:

```
@Test
public void getPersonsForApiConsumerTest() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get(getUri("/consumers/1/persons")))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].name", is("Ligza")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[2].name", is("Vekrir")));

}

@Test
public void getPersonsForApiConsumerMapTest() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get(getUri("/consumers/1/persons/map")))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].name", is("Verkir")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[2].name", is("Ligza")));
}
```

Rest methods with mapping:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{consumerId}/persons")
    public List<PersonDto> getPersonsForApiConsumer(@PathVariable("consumerId") Integer consumerId) throws IOException {
        return apiConsumerService.getPersonsListForApiConsumer(consumerId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{consumerId}/persons/map")
    public Map<ApiConsumerPersonRole, List<Person>> getPersonsForApiConsumerMap(@PathVariable("consumerId") Integer consumerId) throws IOException {
        return apiConsumerService.getPersonsMapForApiConsumer(consumerId);
    }
```

By Postman I can gain data such:

for list:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Ligza",
        "lastName": "Zetasor",
        "role": "REPRESENTATIVE",
        "phone": "123123123",
        "email": "ligza.zetasor@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "firstName": "Vekrir",
        "lastName": "Omegaram",
        "role": "SECURITY_OFFICER",
        "phone": "354654545",
        "email": "vekrir.omegaram@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

for map:

```
{
    "SECURITY_OFFICER": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "firstName": "Vekrir",
            "lastName": "Omegaram",
            "telephone": "354654545",
            "email": "vekrir.omegaram@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "REPRESENTATIVE": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Ligza",
            "lastName": "Zetasor",
            "telephone": "123123123",
            "email": "ligza.zetasor@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "COMPLAINT_OFFICER": [],
    "LOCAL_REPRESENTATIVE": []
}
```

I dont have any clue how to write it properly. I want to check the data inside this list and map.

Is it possible to stream it into that collection or check it easily in the way it is wriiten already?

---

Edit: logs:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[1].firstname", exception: No results for path: $[1]['firstname']

    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:245)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers$1.match(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code -1

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"COMPLAINT_OFFICER":[],"REPRESENTATIVE":[{"id":1,"firstName":"Ligza","lastName":"Zetasor","telephone":"123123123","email":"ligza.zetasor@gmail.com"}],"LOCAL_REPRESENTATIVE":[],"SECURITY_OFFICER":[{"id":4,"firstName":"Vekrir","lastName":"Omegaram","telephone":"354654545","email":"vekrir.omegaram@gmail.com"}]}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[1].firstname", exception: Filter: [1]['firstname'] can only be applied to arrays. Current context is: {COMPLAINT_OFFICER=[], REPRESENTATIVE=[{"id":1,"firstName":"Ligza","lastName":"Zetasor","telephone":"123123123","email":"ligza.zetasor@gmail.com"}], LOCAL_REPRESENTATIVE=[], SECURITY_OFFICER=[{"id":4,"firstName":"Vekrir","lastName":"Omegaram","telephone":"354654545","email":"vekrir.omegaram@gmail.com"}]}

    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:245)
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers$1.match(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: What it the occuring failure and what are the data you´re getting while running your test?

Comment: I have edited my post. I would rather to stream that into collection on which I can operate.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `jsonPath` helpers are very useful for asserting your responses are valid from the perspective of the consumers of your API; these consumers receive a JSON repsonse so it makes sense to perform your assertions on that JSON.

The following assertions will work for the payload from `/consumers/1/persons`

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].firstName", is("Ligza")))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].firstName", is("Vekrir")))
```

So, the array is 0-based and you access entries in each element by the (case sensitive) name.

However, if you really want to assert against the original types (e.g. `PersonDto`) then you can read the entire JSON string and use a JSON mapper (such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)) to deserialize it back into its original class representation. For example:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(getUri("/consumers/1/persons")))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// this uses a TypeReference to inform Jackson about the Lists's generic type
List<PersonDto> actual = mapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), new TypeReference<List<PersonDto>>() {});

// now just assert equality (or whatever) against the actual PersonDto
```

Comment: Ok, that is a very nice solution. But If I have a list of people right there, so I should create List<PersonDto> and map actual several times?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to deserilaize the JSON array into a `List<PersonDto>`. FWIW, I would still recommend getting to grips with `jsonPath`, it's (a) very useful and (b) it probably mimics what your actual consumers are doing i.e. reading JSON rather than deserialising into types which only you (the provider) know about.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I was wondering if there's a way to check if the list is of a certain type. I mean, if I expect a List<Object>, if there's a way that the list I retrieved is really a List<Object>. Kind of "typeof" or "instanceof" but with lists.

Comment: I do not believe Java has reification, which means at runtime a List<Object> is a List, and a List<MyObject> is still a List. There's no way to tell.